# New Relic Slowing Web App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I ran http://www.webpagetest.org on my heroku Rails app, and I noticed that there's two resources at the end of the list that take about 0.5 second off of my page load. These two resources are:

1. https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-100.js
2. https://beacon-3.newrelic.com/...

I then turned off new relic, and reran the performance test. Those two resources are removed and the time was saved.

Why is New Relic doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two resources you mentioned are part of New Relic's Real User Monitoring feature

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/real-user-monitoring

This allows you to monitor your end users browser response time. 
If you think there is a problem with this you may want to open a support ticket at http://support.newrelic.com

Comment: yea it's just to me 0.5+ second is a lot of time.